# Determine if elements of list1 are containted in list2 F#

Tags: list, f#

I have been messing around doing some programming exercises online of F# and I have gotten stuck on this.

So if i have ['a';'b';'c'] and [‘a’;’x’;’y’;’b’;’c’;’e’] it should return true but if I have something like ['a';'b';'c'] and [‘a’;’x’;’a’;’y’;’c’;’e’] it should be false.

Comment: I'm sorry but what am I doing wrong? For getting downvoted?

Comment: People are happy to help if you run into some specific trouble while trying to solve the problem. But if you just copy-paste the questions here without trying, you're likely to get down-voted. (Especially if you do this as a sequence of questions.)

Comment: Ah I see okay Ill try and add some code next time to show I put some effort into it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a set of these values, and use [`Set.IsProperSubsetOf<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353865.aspx) to check for whether the values are contained.

```
let list1 = ['a';'b';'c']
let list2 = ['a';'x';'y';'b';'c';'e']
let list3 = ['a';'x';'a';'y';'c';'e']

let first = Set.ofList list1
let second = Set.ofList list2
let third = Set.ofList list3

let containedInSecond = first.IsProperSubsetOf second
let containedInThird = first.IsProperSubsetOf third
```

Running this in F# Interactive will print (for the last two lines) your desired results:

```
val containedInSecond : bool = true
val containedInThird : bool = false
```

Comment: Oh wow didn't know of that property. Thanks for the help, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Valener Technically, that's creating a different type - a set, from the lists.  Sets are perfect for doing contains/intersection/etc type operations.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this was downvoted...

Comment: @ildjam Me neither - nor, really, why the original question was closed, though at least the OP got their answer ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey I thought I am supposed to close the thread once the question has been answered?

Comment: @Valener Yes, and that's the green checkbox - somebody voted this answer down (hit the down arrow) for some reason - not sure why, but glad you've got an answer now :)